# DRF - Validation PrimaryRelatedField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I created a serializer:

```
def validate_users(users):
    # doing some validation
    return users


class MySerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    user_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        source='users',
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        validators=[validate_users]
    )
```

The validation does not work when `many=True` because `validators` is not pass into `ManyRelatedField` https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/c10f2266222c434485889b08cc1463acdb8fa169/rest_framework/relations.py#L146.

There is also a note:

[image]

How to run validation using `validator` property after `to_internal_value` when using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with many=`True`?

Comment: What about the [`validate_<field_name>(...)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#field-level-validation) method?

Comment: I'd like to use `validator` property of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`